# How to combine text in parse function with other (unparsed) text for plot annotation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a simple annotation to a plot that reads: "R^2: 0.90", where the 2 is shown as an exponent. I am having issues because the parse function removes the trailing 0 from my R-squared value, but I can't figure out how to paste together a parsed string and an unparsed string.

```
R2 <- 0.90
R2.ann <- parse(text=(paste("R^2:", sprintf("%.2f", round(R2,2)), sep="")))
R2.ann <- paste(parse(text="R^2"), ": ", sprintf("%.2f", round(R2,2)), sep="")
# And other variations on this, using as.character() or separating the parts into individual variables

# Here is a simple ggplot that the annotation right in the middle
ggplot(data=data.frame(0,0), aes(x = 0, y = 0)) + geom_point(color="white") + annotate("text", label=R2.ann, x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: You can do `R2.ann <- parse(text=paste("R^2:", shQuote(sprintf("%.2f", round(R2,2))), sep=""))`.
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create a valid `?plotmath` expression. Since its needs to be parsed by R, it needs to be a valid expression. You can combine numbers and strings in a `?plotmath` expression with `*`. So a proper expression would be

```
expression(R^2 * ": * "0.1")
```

for example. We can use `bquote` to insert your actual value.

```
bquote(R^2 * ": " * .(sprintf("%.2f", round(R2,2))))
```

But the `annotate()` command in ggplot needs to take a character value, not an expression, so we can `deparse()` that.

```
R2.ann <- deparse(bquote(R^2 * ": " * .(sprintf("%.2f", round(R2,2)))))
```

Then when you plot, you need to tell `annotate()` that it needs to do the parsing

```
ggplot(data=data.frame(0,0), aes(x = 0, y = 0)) + 
  geom_point(color="white") + 
  annotate("text", label=R2.ann, x=0, y=0, parse=TRUE)
```